# How can I switch to Flash fullscreen mode in an OpenLaszlo application?

Tags: flash, fullscreen, openlaszlo

In an OpenLaszlo application using the SWF10 runtime, how can I switch the application into fullscreen mode? How can I detect the status of the application, is there an attribute which gets set when the mode is switched?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately the fullscreen feature is not documented well. When I implemented that feature for the platform, the documentation piece was never added - although the functionality is documented in the LzView API.

Here's a small example showing how the fullscreen feature works:

```
<canvas allowfullscreen="true">

  <button text="Go Fullscreen" onclick="canvas.setAttribute('fullscreen', true)" 
          enabled="${canvas.fullscreen == false}"/>

  <button y="50" text="Leave Fullscreen" onclick="canvas.setAttribute('fullscreen', false)" 
          enabled="${canvas.fullscreen == true}"/>

  <handler name="onfullscreen">
    Debug.info('onfullscreen: canvas.fullscreen=' + canvas.fullscreen);
  </handler>

</canvas>
```

You have to set the attribute allowfullscreen to true on canvas. The canvas.fullscreen property will be set to true, when the application enters fullscreen mode. The corresponding event is canvas.onfullscreen, which you can use in handlers.

If you use your own code for embedding the generated SWF into the HTML page (and not the OpenLaszlo generated HTML page), please make sure that you set attribute/property

> allowfullscreen="true"

in your embedding code.